# ¿Cómo leer el siguiente json con http.get?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Cuento con el siguiente json pero ¿cómo leo los datos de persona?

```
{“Personas”: [ {“id”: 0,“name”: “Miguel Sanchez”,“age”: 306,},{“id”: 1,“name”: “Juan Perez”,“age”: 20,}]}
```

Por ejemplo quiero obtener algo así

```
 [{“id”: 0,“name”: “Miguel Sanchez”,“age”: 306,},{“id”: 1,“name”: “Juan Perez”,“age”: 20,}]
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
http.get('assets/inhabitants.json')
  .subscribe((response: Response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Sé que no resuelve nada pero no se me ocurre como obtener un array de personas

Comment: El archivo json debe estar en el formato correcto, y usa console.log(response.Personas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola para poder leer el JSON primero debes parsearlo, de todas maneras tengo serias dudas si es un JSON correctamente formado ya que en tu ejemplo el contenido del documento JSON es:

```
{“Personas”: [{ {“id”: 0,“name”: “Miguel Sanchez”,“age”: 306,},{“id”: 1,“name”: “Juan Perez”,“age”: 20,}}]
```

Y los caracteres `“`,`”` no son validos como delimitadores, deberia reemplazarse los `“`,`”` por `"` y ser así el formato del documento JSON para estar correctamente formateado:

```
{"Personas": [{ {"id": 0,"name": "Miguel Sanchez","age": 306,},{"id": 1,"name": "Juan Perez","age": 20,}}]}
```

Puedes validar que tu documento este correctamente formateado con el siguiente recurso [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/) por ejemplo.

Dicho todo esto para poder leerlo debes convertir el contenido del archivo JSON a un Objeto Javascript usando el metodo `.json()` de la clase `Response` por lo que tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
http.get('/assets/inhabitants.json').subscribe((response: Response) => {
    let personas = response.json().Personas;
    console.log(personas); // devolveria lo que solicitas.
});
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Sera porque tienes el json mal formado?
En vez de:

```
 {"Personas": {[...]} }
```

Deberia de ser:

```
{"Personas": [...]}
```

Fíjate en que tienes los corchetes [] encerado entre llaves {}.

Y por ultimo, verifica que este restornando un objeto json y no un texto plano.
Si te esta retornando un texto plano, utiliza JSON.parse() para convertirlo a un objeto:

```
http.get('assets/inhabitants.json')
  .subscribe((response: Response) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(response).Personas);
  });
```

Comment: había probado hacer un scope adentro del response pero me dice que no existe esa propiedad.